# MYSQL query to find out common bugs in various versions

Tags: mysql, sql, select, group-by

I have the data of some bug across various versions. I need to find out the common bugs which are propagating from old releases. In the below data sample, i am interested to know the common version bugs in this example: "This is a 8.x old bug"  i.e. last 3 lines in the data

```
9.1.1.5   |xymodel1 |227501| This is a 9.x new bug 
8.1.2.9   |xymodel1 |227501| This a 8.x new bug 
8.1.1.5   |xymodel1 |227501| This a 8.x new1 bug 
7.1.2.30  |xy6700   |287640| This is a 7.x new bug
7.1.2.30  |xy6700   |288185| This is a 7.x new1 bug
9.1.1.5   |xymodel1 |227501| This is a 9.x new bug 
10.1.2.30 |xy6700   |288368| This is a 10.x new bug 
10.1.1.6  |xymodel1 |227501| This is a 10.x new bug 
8.1.1.5   |xymodel1 |227501| This is a 8.x old bug
9.1.1.5   |xymodel1 |227501| This is a 8.x old bug
10.1.1.5  |xymodel1 |227501| This is a 8.x old bug
```

I ran the following query which should have given me the common bug across 8.x,9.x and 10.x as there is an AND condition.
But in results I see, few other accompanied rows as well, which are not common across the three releases.

```
select * from issue_table
where
bug_name in (select bug_name from issue_table where version like '8.%' and '9.%' and '10.%')
```

Results:  Top two rows should not have come in the results as they are not common across releases.

```
version   model     data    bug_name
8.1.2.9   xymodel1  227501  This a 8.x new bug
8.1.1.5   xymodel1  227501  This a 8.x new1 bug
8.1.1.5   xymodel1  227501  This is a 8.x old bug
9.1.1.5   xymodel1  227501  This is a 8.x old bug
10.1.1.5  xymodel1  227501  This is a 8.x old bug
```

I was expecting :

```
version   model     data    bug_name
8.1.1.5   xymodel1  227501  This is a 8.x old bug
9.1.1.5   xymodel1  227501  This is a 8.x old bug
10.1.1.5  xymodel1  227501  This is a 8.x old bug
```

SQL Fiddle link can be found here: https://www.db-fiddle.com/#&togetherjs=VTGbSRMgIO

Can you guys help me in editing the query to pick just the common bug in all three releases.

Comment: What is "common" in this context? And how do you identify a bug?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use an `exists` condition for each possible major version:

```
select i.*
from issue_table i
where
    exists(select 1 from issue_table i1 where i1.bug_name = i.bug_name and i1.version like '8.%')
    and exists(select 1 from issue_table i1 where i1.bug_name = i.bug_name and i1.version like '9.%')
    and exists(select 1 from issue_table i1 where i1.bug_name = i.bug_name and i1.version like '10.%')
```

Although this might seem a bit lengthy, this should be an efficient option, provided that you have an index on `(bug_name, version)`.

In your DB Fiddle, this returns:

```
| version  | model    | data   | bug_name              |
| -------- | -------- | ------ | --------------------- |
| 8.1.1.5  | xymodel1 | 227501 | This is a 8.x old bug |
| 9.1.1.5  | xymodel1 | 227501 | This is a 8.x old bug |
| 10.1.1.5 | xymodel1 | 227501 | This is a 8.x old bug |
```

Comment: Thanks GMB. Nice solution. I tried on a smaller subset of data and it is working fine. But when I run on some 80,000 rows, the query is forever running. Is there any fast way possible?

Comment: @ran1n: do you have the suggested index in place?

Answer (score 1):

This might be what you are looking for:

```
select * 
from issue_table
where bug_name in (
    select bug_name 
    from issue_table 
    where version like '8.%' 
    or version like '9.%' 
    or version like '10.%' 
    group by bug_name 
    having count(*) = 3)
```

The sub-select counts the bugs that are present in all three versions.

You can also write this as a join:

```
select it.* 
from (
    select bug_name 
    from issue_table 
    where version like '8.%' 
    or version like '9.%' 
    or version like '10.%' 
    group by bug_name 
    having count(*) = 3
) tmp, issue_table it 
where it.bug_name = tmp.bug_name
```

Comment: Thanks Pritaeas. But in actual field we have 100 more versions. The data is just a representation. This -> having count(*) = 3)   may not work when versions increase or decrease

Comment: You can create something (e.g. a stored procedure) to build and execute your query, so that when a version is added, it is also automatically included in your query.